# DOM change font color by using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a beginner of JS and HTML.
I encounter a problem with changing the font color by using addEventListener

here is my part of HTML code

```
<form>
   <input type = 'color' class = 'color'>
</form>
```

here is my js code.

```
// this is for class color 
const color = document.querySelectorAll('.color');

// I have 2 div block which contains messages.

const showTextBox = document.querySelectorAll('.mtext1');

// for each message, they correspond to the different color boxes.

color.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e)

    showTextBox[index].style.color = color[index].value;
  })
});
```

the situation I encounter is when I click the color box, it pops up the Palette, and then you have to "click" again for choosing the color. However, that addEventListener only available for the first click.

What I thought is maybe I can use nested addEventListener?
or does javascript has a more efficient way to change color dynamically(or responsively) to solve double click situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this solution. Use **input** event instead of **click**.

```
const color = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
const showTextBox = document.querySelectorAll('.mtext1');

color.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    showTextBox[index].style.color = element.value;
  })
});
```

Comment: God, you are so genius. I mean, there is tons of 'Event' you can choose. How can you remember all of them?

Comment: Thanks ))) I remember only those events, which I usually use. Here are all js events list, it will be helpful for you  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp